# i can't invoke a function directly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
{

    bool GameEnd = false;

    public float restartDelay = 1f;

    public void GameOver()
    {
        if(GameEnd == false)
        {
            GameEnd = true;
            Debug.Log("GAMEOVER");
            Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
        }
        
        void Restart()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }

    }    
}
```

I want to invoke "restart" with a delay but it shows "it couldn't be called"

what's wrong?

Comment: because it's local function? you did a typo and it should not be local?

Comment: i have to make a public function?

Comment: Right now your "Restart" method is local to (only accessible to) the surrounding GameOver method

Answer (score 0):

Declare both methods in the class scope:
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class YourClass: MonoBehaviour { //presumably monobehaviour

```
    bool GameEnd = false;
    public float restartDelay = 1f;

    private IEnumerator coroutine;

    void Start() {
        coroutine = Restart(); 
    }
    public void GameOver()
    {
        if(GameEnd == false)
        {
            GameEnd = true;
            Debug.Log("GAMEOVER");
            Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
        }
        StartCoroutine(coroutine);
    } 

    IEnumerator Restart()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Not debugged, exmaple just to show you how it works.

Comment: yeah, but in this way, there isn't any delay, I need 1 second delay

Comment: then trry a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). Sample in the answer

Comment: not debuggued, hope its clear enough to guide you :)

Comment: Assets\GameManager.cs(27,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IEnumerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) now it says this, I'm sorry but I'm a beginner. Maybe I need to use a library

Comment: try adding `using System.Collections.Generic`. Updated in answer

Comment: you can check also the namespace suggested by the editor, or google that out. It will be faster for you, and more useful regarding code learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is **local** (== nested) within the `GameOver` method.

In order to use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) it needs to be on class level scope like

```
bool GameEnd = false;

public float restartDelay = 1f;

public void GameOver()
{
    if(GameEnd == false)
    {
        GameEnd = true;
        Debug.Log("GAMEOVER");
        Invoke(nameof(Restart), restartDelay);
    }
}   

void Restart()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

otherwise Unity won't find it.

Comment: Seems I am *way* behind the times on language features... When did local functions become a thing?

Comment: @Immersive since [c# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) though the concept itself already exists in many languages ;)